# Python Statsmodels ARIMA: How to add/combine a feature(variable) in the model

Tags: python, statsmodels

Hello I am modeling an ARIMA in Python using statsmodels.

The code is below:

```
p = d = q = range(0, 2)

# Generate all different combinations of p, q and q triplets
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))

# Generate all different combinations of seasonal p, q and q triplets
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 1) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]

print('Examples of parameter combinations for Seasonal ARIMA...')
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[1]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[2]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[3]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[4]))

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # specify to ignore warning messages

for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)

            results = mod.fit()

            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue


mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                order=(1, 1, 1),
                                seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12),
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)

results = mod.fit()

print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

As the result of the model I get this diagnostic table:

```
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ma.L1         -0.6255      0.077     -8.165      0.830      -0.376      -0.475
ar.S.L12      -0.0010      0.001      1.732      0.003      -0.000       0.002
ma.S.L12      -0.8769      0.026    -33.811      0.000      -0.928      -0.826
sigma2         30.0972      0.004     22.634      0.000       0.089       0.106
==============================================================================
```

To improve the model, I want to get rid of the ma.L1 and want to add a feature(a new variable) made by me. But I do not know how to add a variable into this model. Particularly, I have a list of numbers like this [2.34, 3.22, 2.11, ...] same length as the dataset I used for this ARIMA. I want to add this list as a variable into the ARIMA model OR I should say combine this new variable with the ARIMA model. Any idea how should I do ?

Comment: Use `exog` for additional explanatory variables.

Comment: Great. I just checked that it takes array_like. How exactly this exog is perceived in the model? I mean behind of the code, how this exog is processed? in a regression? if regression, then what kind of regression?

Comment: And can I put multiple variables in this exog?

Comment: http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html#ARIMA-Example-4:-ARMAX-(Friedman)

Comment: `exog` is similar to other models such as OLS. When we use `numpy.asarray(exog)` it needs to have observations in rows and variables in columns. (If it's 1-dimensional then it will be reshaped internally.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this out.